# Converting Integer to Double Precision in fortran

Tags: fortran

I am seeing a strange problem, when I convert a large int to float, the values are not the same,

Here's a test program that replicates the problem

```
program test

integer a


a = 135000011
b = dble(a)

write(*,*) a, b

end
```

This prints

```
135000011 135000012
```

What is happening? How can I circumvent this?

Comment: Always use `implicit none` in Fortran.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error and how to fix this?

Since the value of `b` is not declared, fortran implicitly assumes its to be real, so to mitigate and correct the issue b should be declared as double precision

full program here

```
program test

integer a
double precision b

a = 135000011
b = dble(a)

write(*,*) a, b

end
```

This prints

```
135000011 135000011.00000
```

Comment: Use "implicit none" and the compiler will not allow you implicitly typed variables.

Comment: Perhaps good to add an explanation, that the precision of  `real` does not suffice here to cover all integers of this magnitude. The spacing is bigger than 1.

Comment: Also double precision is a bit 1980s - see the duplicate for the modern way